# Unknown Laravel Exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, routes, vue-resource

I'm setting up routes between my Vue.js app and Laravel. I've [setup CSRF with Vue.js](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-add-csrftoken-when-using-laravel-and-vue-resource?page=1), but Laravel now throws the error below when I try and use my PageController@store method. It appears to be linked to the type hinting in my PageController: I removed all type hints, and this error disappeared. However, I wasn't getting any data returned.

> "message": "No query results for model [App\Page]."
>   "exception": 
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",

This is unexpected, as my store method only returns the request as JSON (I have also tried this with the store method empty).

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json($request);
}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::resource('/admin/resource/pages', 'PageController');
```

And lastly, here's my Vue.js method that sends the data to Laravel.

```
post (model){
    this.$http.put("/admin/resource/pages/store", {
        _method: "put",
        model: model
    }, {}).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Any help is appreciated thank-you.

**Full error stack:**

```
{
    "message": "No query results for model [App\\Page].",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
    "line": 200,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "prepareException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/app/Exceptions/Handler.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 83,
            "function": "render",
            "class": "App\\Exceptions\\Handler",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handleException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php",
            "line": 75,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
            "line": 63,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
            "line": 66,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 681,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 656,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 622,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 611,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/tempfiles/75/blog/public/index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Page Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // return response()->json(Page::all());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json($request);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Page $page)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Page $page)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Page $page)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Page $page)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried with `this.$http.put` ? I assume you also care about `_token` the csrf field

Comment: I'll give it shot, thanks! I'm sending my csrf token with all requests - its setup in my entry script: `Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;`

Comment: @C2486 Still the same error message returned from Laravel, but I'll continue to use `this.$http.put`

Comment: Can you include full controller code? Is your store method looks exactly as you showed here? If you have custom code in RouteServiceProvider you can include this too

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I've stripped it back for testing, this is all I'm currently using (included in my answer at the bottom). My store method looks exactly like that, and I haven't changed my RouteServiceProvider. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `put` method in fact you are hitting:

```
public function update(Request $request, Page $page)
{
    //
}
```

controller method. Because you have here `Page $page` as argument, Laravel using route model binding automatically run:

```
Page::findOrFail($page);
```

and because you set in Vue url as `/admin/resource/pages/store` in fact it will run:

```
Page::findOrFail('store');
```

Of course I assume you don't have any page record with id = 'store' so that's the reason why you are getting this error.

So probably you should correct your route in Vue, to pass valid id instead of `store` or use other method  for example `POST` with valid route.

In console you can run:

```
php artisan route:list
```

to see all available routes.

Comment: Thank-you, `php artisan route:list` revealed that my store method is actually called via `/admin/resource/pages` with the `POST` method. This went against my own assumption of `/admin/resource/pages/store`. This is now working as expected, thanks.

Comment: @TheMintyMate Glad I was able to help you :)